# Can the artificer infusion Radiant Weapon blind a ranged or hidden attacker?

Tags: dnd-5e, stealth, artificer, blind, artificer-infusions

The artificer infusion [Radiant Weapon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#RadiantWeapon) has the following property as one of its effects (E:RftLW, p. 62; WGtE, p. 182):

> [...] As a reaction immediately after being hit by an attack, the wielder can expend 1 charge and cause the attacker to be blinded until the end of the attacker’s next turn, unless the attacker succeeds on a Constitution saving throw against your spell save DC. [...]

This effect does not impose any restriction on what kind of attacker can be blinded by this (e.g. "after being hit by a melee attack" or "an attacker you can see"). However, to me, it seems odd that the weapon can blind a long-ranged attacker or someone who is hidden (and therefore the wielder of the radiant weapon doesn't even know the attacker's position).

Can the artificer infusion Radiant Weapon really blind a ranged or hidden attacker?

Is that really how the infusion works, or am I missing something? I know the official artificer is recent, but is there any errata or Sage Advice about this effect of the infusion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## They are Blinded

Unless the feature offers a specific exception, or there's a general rule, things do what they say they do. No exception is given in the description of Radiant Weapon to creatures that are hidden or ranged attackers either specifically or generally that would prevent them from being blinded by this effect, so it would apply to them as well.

As a counter example, consider the spell *[Blindness/Deafness](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/blindness-deafness)*:

> You can blind or deafen a foe. Choose one creature **that you can see within range** to make a Constitution saving throw. If it fails, the target is either blinded or deafened (your choice) for the duration. At the end of each of its turns, the target can make a Constitution saving throw. On a success, the spell ends.

In the case of this spell, it specifically calls out that they must be both seen and in range. The Radiant Weapon effect does not have such requirements.

Comment: It may also be worth noting that the rules on [unseen attackers and targets](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#UnseenAttackersandTargets) state: "If you are hidden — both unseen and unheard — when you make an attack, you give away your location when the attack hits or misses." The rules on [hiding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#Hiding) also indicate that creatures remain alert during combat, so unhidden creatures' positions remain known. Thus, immediately after the attack, the artificer will know the attacker's position regardless.